# The hover border on tags is always blue

Tags: bug, tags, design

I realize that you basically just copied the color scheme from the beta theme for a lot of aspects of this one, including the tags. However, beta sites don't have required and moderator-only tags, and it appears this theme didn't get any special casing for them. This causes the required (dark grey) and moderator-only (red) tags to have a blue border when hovering over them, which looks rather odd:

[image: Example of blue borders]

Can these special tags not be affected by the hover state, or have their own hover states?

Comment: For the sake of clarity: beta sites do have those kinds of tags, but (naturally) on their meta sites only.  Meta.SE design copied the main-beta design.

Comment: **+1** I was going to post this myself.